# phpmailer suddenly got very slow

Tags: phpmailer

I use phpmailer for sending emails and while it worked flawlesly until now, I noticed that sending emails got very very slow, around 2-3 minutes. The mails are sent, but the waiting time is killing me.

My code is:

```
   protected function SendPHPMailerMail($from = null, $name = null, $subject = null, $message = null)
{

    require_once ('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');


    if($from && $name && $subject && $message)
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        //$mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';            
        $mail->isSMTP();

        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                 // sets the prefix to the servier
        $mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $mail->Username   = 'x@gmail.com';  // GMAIL username
        $mail->Password   = 'pass';            // GMAIL password
        $mail->AddReplyTo($from, $name);
        $mail->AddAddress('x@gmail.com', 'Me');
        $mail->SetFrom('x@gmail.com', 'Me');
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $message;
        $mail->Send();
    }
}
```

I tried debugging, there are no errors. I read in a different question thread that using gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com'); worked for some, but not for me. I haven't changed anything on the server and this popped out of nowhere. Not sure what to do.

Thanks!

edit: used SMTPdebug=2 and this is what I get

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 90sm16517084otw.3 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.host.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [107.182.234.254]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.host.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [107.182.234.254]250-   SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: Y29udGFjdEBmaWxlY2x1c3Rlci5jb20=
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -> SERVER: Z2l6bW8uMTIzcXdl
SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Accepted
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<x@gmail.com>
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 OK 90sm16517084otw.3 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<x@gmail.com>
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 OK 90sm16517084otw.3 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Go ahead 90sm16517084otw.3 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 20:44:01 +0000
CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Me <x@gmail.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Me <x@gmail.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: X <sender@gmail.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Partnership and business development
CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <6dae364927ad751cc524f07a77f5eea1@www.host.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.16 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: message
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: .
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 OK 1476996370 90sm16517084otw.3 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection 90sm16517084otw.3 - gsmtp
```

I replaced the actual values of the site and emails.

Comment: Read the docs, set SMTPDebug = 2 and you'll be able to see exactly what is taking the time. You'll also see in the docs that it says that SMTP can be slow, often deliberately so, so it's not suitable for use during page submissions - hand it off to a local mail server.

Comment: I understand that SMTP can be slow, but why it became slow after 6 months+? Initially, I thought it was a gmail problem, but after 4 days, it seems very unlikely. I'll try smtpdebug=2 to see what outputs.

Comment: I've added the edits to the original post. Not sure if the debugg is telling me anything

Comment: **PLEASE CHANGE YOUR GMAIL PASSWORD SINCE YOU INCLUDED IT IN THE DEBUG OUTPUT**  The line before `235 2.7.0 Accepted` is your password encoded as per SMTP.

Comment: uh, I missed that :( thanks for letting me know